# Electrostatic and gravitational forces

Tags: newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law

When I first studied physics in my first year at university, one thing that struck me was the way the gravitational and electrostatic forces look so similar:

$F = k_e\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$ (Coulomb's law) vs $F = G \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$ (Newton's law)

To the naive observer, the only differences seem to be that we know of positive and negative electric charges, but only positive masses, and charges of the same polarity repulse, while the opposite is true of masses. This would seem to suggest that one could consider electric charges as 'imaginary masses': put two imaginary numbers into Newton's law, and they will repulse each other.

And of course, once I started down that path, why not allow negative masses too? Masses of opposite signs would flee from each other, and tend to clump together with masses of the same sign, thus leading to a universe where you would only observer the same polarity of mass.

I am sure better minds than I have come up with these ideas in the past and found good reasons to dismiss them, but I have never seen any discussion of this. Are there any articles about this subjects?

Comment: As I understand it the similarity led Einstein to initially pursue the idea of unifying gravitational and electrical fields, which turned out to be wrong

Comment: I think it is due to the similarities between charge and mass,negative mass has not been found yet but mass and charge are very similar.

Comment: @BobD Wasn't that the work with Kaluza and Klein, which later led to string theory?

Comment: @bobd it was just a thought . and his theory consist of some unusual facts